# Filtering by a value that's in an array

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DF:

```
print(test_df)

Out:
                           Action_flat Resource
0                        autoscaling:*      [*]
1                         cloudwatch:*      [*]
2           cloudformation:CreateStack      [*]
3   cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents      [*]
4               datapipeline:Describe*      [*]
5               datapipeline:Describe*      
6               datapipeline:Describe*      ['---', '---']
..                                 ...      ...
```

I want to filter this DF to only have rows where the Resource is [*]

This code however returns an empty DF:

```
test_df = test_df[test_df['Resource'] == '[*]']
print(test_df)

Out:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Action_flat, Resource]
Index: []
```

What is the proper way to filter by an array value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the `str` accessor when you have a list as a value:

```
output_df = df[df['Resource'].str[0].eq("*")]
```

If a string with multiple `'*'` can occur and you just want to check where one  `'*'` is present , use another condition:

```
output_df = df[df['Resource'].str[0].eq("*") & df['Resource'].str.len().eq(1)]
```

Comment: This works with my updated DF (when the Resource array also contains a list of values). Thank you

Comment: @MayankPorwal Thank you. Already upvoted yours. May be you can check membership against a slice of the string string. :) `str(x) [0]`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
In [661]: df = df[df['Resource'].apply(lambda x: '*' in str(x))]

In [662]: df
Out[662]: 
                          Action_flat Resource
0                       autoscaling:*      [*]
1                        cloudwatch:*      [*]
2          cloudformation:CreateStack      [*]
3  cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents      [*]
4              datapipeline:Describe*      [*]
```